# Python - Executing multiple shell commands one after another

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to execute multiple shell commands one after another. The commands are received from a remote device through socket. What i need to do is to create a shell that is accessible remotely. With `subprocess.Popen` i am able to execute commands and get output. But if i want to execute `cd MyDIR` and then `ls -l`. If I execute it as 2 lines of code, i get file listing of the parent directory rather than the the directory i cd into. Using `cd MyDIR && ls -l` gives the required result. If i use the communicate method, i am not getting any result and also the stdin gets closed. Can someone help me with a piece of code?

**Edit**

The solution given here [Interacting with bash from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python) doesn't solve my problem as i want to keep the shell active as long as possible and as much as needed. Trying the solution on that pages gives a message that `IO operation on closed file.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interacting with bash from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes it looks like a duplicate but i want to solve the `IO operation on closed file` error. I want to keep the communication active.

Comment: Looks like it can be done easier if you'll listen with bash. Just `nc -k -l 4444 | bash`.

Comment: @Raz I cant listen with `nc -k -l 4444 | bash` Because, bash is only a part of what i want to do. I am actually trying to run shell commands using Telegram bot. I will remotely send the command and bot executes it on my RPI and it will send me back the response. This is what i actually need.

Comment: May be you can start tmux session and interact with it. Check this [lib](https://github.com/tony/libtmux). It can connect to session and do `pane.send_keys('echo hey send now')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code helps

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep
from fcntl import fcntl, F_GETFL, F_SETFL
from os import O_NONBLOCK, read

# run the shell as a subprocess:
p = Popen(['python', 'shell.py'],
        stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False)
# set the O_NONBLOCK flag of p.stdout file descriptor:
flags = fcntl(p.stdout, F_GETFL) # get current p.stdout flags
fcntl(p.stdout, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)
# issue command:
p.stdin.write('command\n')
# let the shell output the result:
sleep(0.1)
# get the output
while True:
    try:
        print read(p.stdout.fileno(), 1024),
    except OSError:
        # the os throws an exception if there is no data
        print '[No more data]'
        break
```

Here is the source http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html