# Replicate shell environment in python for executing bash commands

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a bash script from inside python using the `subprocess` module. The problem is that this bash script relies on many environment variables that are set in my `.bashrc` file. What I want is for python subprocess to exactly replicate the environment that is setup when I launch a terminal window. So far I tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args=['my-script.sh', '--additional_args'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=os.environ.copy(), shell=True)
output_buffer, return_code = p.communicate()
```

But then read somewhere that even after doing `shell=True`, the `.bashrc` file is still not loaded, and that i should try something like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args=['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'my_script.sh', '--additional_args'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output_buffer, return_code = p.communicate()
```

But with this function call, I get this error:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
bash: cannot set terminal process group (2071): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Comment: Might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

**Bashrc**

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc  |grep LOLO
export LOLO="/foo/bar"
```

**Bash**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo $LOLO
```

**Python**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess, os
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/sbin:/sbin:" + my_env["PATH"]
subprocess.Popen('/home/m.ortiz.montealegre/lolo/script.sh', env=my_env)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python script.py
/foo/bar
```

The thing is, if you add new values (aliases / variables) to your bashrc you'll need to restart your terminal in order to bashrc gets executed and make those changes availables in the environment.

I've found the references to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i)

**Note:** From a subshell process you can't set environment variables to the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

[xonsh](https://xon.sh/) shell should be useful for such mixing of bash and python

> xonsh is a Python-powered shell that combines the flexibility of Python with > the convenience of a shell environment. It supports interactive use, > scripting, and seamless integration with existing Python libraries and tools.