# Shell Script that does chroot and execute commands in chroot

Tags: bash, shell, chroot

If in shell script I write

```
chroot /home/mayank/chroot/codebase
cd SBC
```

when I run this shell script It does go in the `chroot` but does not execute the command `cd SBC`, 
when I exit `chroot` then it executes `cd SBC`.

How can I achieve something that does `chroot` and execute commands in `chroot` through shell script ??

Comment: try `chroot /home/whatever "COMMAND"` chroot can have command

Comment: chroot /home/whatever "COMMAND"

I even tried that, what actually happened was, it didn't go to chroot, but executed that "COMMAND" command successfully ..

Comment: Moreover, I have many commands, that is to be run under chroot 
There must be some way ???

Comment: `COMMAND` can execute a script in the chroot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)

Answer (score 22):

When you run `chroot` without telling it what to do, it will try to start chrooted interactive shell session. So your script would "pause" at that point and when you are done with that interactive shell session, it continues out of chroot again.

One of the quick and dirt options would be to abuse here-document, like this:

```
chroot /home/mayank/chroot/codebase /bin/bash <<"EOT"
cd /tmp/so
ls -l
echo $$
EOT
```

Which takes all lines up to `EOT` and feeds them into `bash` started through `chroot`. Those double quotes around `"EOT"` should ensure bash passes the content not trying to expand variables and such. Hence that `echo $$` should be PID of the inner chrooted `bash`.

Comment: Thereis exist way to expand some variables?

Comment: @AndreyReeshkov You can use `<<EOT` without double quotes as mentioned, but then the usual processing (parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion) takes place in calling shell and you must  escape all that is to be passed literally into the child process.

Comment: Nice post! I also have the same problem and I also found another way with python interaction, FYI.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python

Comment: @AndreyReeshkov `chroot MYVAR=test bash <<"EOT"\necho $MYVAR\nEOT`

Comment: @n0099 Not working. `bash: MYVAR=test: No such file or directory`. Please, clarify the command.

Comment: @OndrejK. *and you must escape all that is to be passed literally into the child process* - Please, elaborate on that. What does this mean?

Comment: @AntonSamokat If you don't double qoute `"EOT"`, the calling shell will already perform all the expansions... so in that example `echo $$` would not be PID of the "inner" shell, but the calling one (already expanded / substituted before passing it). In that case, if one wanted to prevent such expansion, the sequence would have to be escape, e.g. in that case: `echo \$\$`. You can also check out the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) esp. the paragraph under the format.

Comment: @AntonSamokat `chroot /home/mayank/chroot/codebase /usr/bin/env MYVAR=test bash ...` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224105/how-to-pass-an-environment-variable-when-change-rooting

Answer (score 5):

somewhat I found a solution,

chroot /work3/tmp_GU/$build_env/sbcbuild/chroot ./test.sh

after chroot giving a script there is working fine for me.

test.sh present in the chroot folder.
All commands in test.sh will be executed in chroot folder.

So basically giving a command after chroot

man chroot

chroot [OPTION] NEWROOT [COMMAND [ARG]...]