# My Bash script ends after entering chroot environment

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

My question:

After the following lines in my script, the script ends unexpectedly. I am trying to enter chroot inside of a bash script. How can I make this work

[I am writing a script that installs Gentoo](https://github.com/LJB018/Gentoo-Simple-Installer)

```
echo " Entering the new environment"


chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash 

source /etc/profile 

export PS1="(chroot) ${PS1}"
```

Comment: Has `PS1` been defined previously? With the shown snippet, `PS1` is accessed before it has been defined.

Comment: @zois No, I just got that code from [here.](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base)

Comment: "chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash"- at this moment you start new child process, so rest of your script will not be executed until you exit from child bash process.

Comment: @Saboteur Okay, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: You can specify a bash script to run inside the chroot like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51312156/530160

Comment: You are starting an **interactive** bash here. The script does not _end_, it just waits dutifully that you enter something.

Comment: @zois That wouldn't matter. By default, the expansion of an undefined parameter is an empty string, not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chroot command will start new child bash process, so rest of your script will not be executed until you quit from child bash process.
So instead of /bin/bash just run your script in chroot:

```
chroot /mnt/gentoo myscript.sh
```

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " Entering the new environment"

source /etc/profile 
export PS1="(chroot) ${PS1}"
```

Comment: This doesn't run an interactive shell at all. It runs `myscript.sh` as a script, and when that script exits, so does `chroot`.

Comment: If you need interactive shell with chroot, raise separate question. This question is about running script.