# Interacting with bash through python without terminating

Tags: python, bash, process, subprocess, popen

I am trying to create a process that interacts with the /bin/bash shell and get information or execute commands. I do not want to close the process as I want to preserve the state for future interactions.

I tried the solution on the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python) but the process is terminated after one communication.

Going through the python `subprocess` API, I find that `subprocess.check_output()` is perfect for this. However, similar to `Popen.communicate()` this kills the process after one execution.

The last approach that seems to work but is unsafe and results in deadlocks is using `Popen.stdin.write` and `Popen.stdout.read`. The read operation goes into an infinite wait if an EOF is not found.

Is there a safer and simpler way to achieve this?

EDIT:
More stuff I tried:

```
import subprocess
import select
import os

process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=True, text=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('export SOMETHING=10000abc\n')
process.stdin.flush()
process.stdin.write('echo $SOMETHING\n')
process.stdin.flush()

r, w, e = select.select([process.stdout], [process.stdin], [], 0)
if process.stdout in r:
  print (os.read(process.stdout.fileno(), 50))
else:
  print ("Nothing to read")
```

The output for this is always `Nothing to read`

Comment: You should use `pexpect`.

Comment: Use `readline` instead of `read`.

Comment: readline() faces the same issue as read(), it can result in a deadlock. So far I am thinking of adding a timeout on the read operations to break out of the deadlock.

Comment: The problem is probably due to stdio buffering when standard output is a pipe. This is why you should use `pexpect`, it works around this by using a pty.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

```
import subprocess
import select
import os

process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=True, text=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('export SOMETHING=10000abc\n')
process.stdin.flush()
process.stdin.write('echo $SOMETHING\n')
process.stdin.flush()

r, w, e = select.select([process.stdout], [process.stdin], [], 0.1)
result = ""
while process.stdout in r:
    result += os.read(process.stdout.fileno(), 100).decode("utf-8")
    r, w, e = select.select([process.stdout], [], [], 0.1)
process.kill()
print (result)
```