# What shell does Python's subprocess use?

Tags: python, subprocess

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python) demonstrates how to use Python's `subprocess` module to interact with `bash` from Python.

So if `subprocess` *doesn't* use the system's default shell, then what shell *does* it use to run commands like this:

```
    import subprocess

    print subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-la"])
```

Comment: on Linux `ls` is normal program - `/bin/ls` - so it can send it directly to system to run program.

Comment: Yes, what makes you think a shell is used or needed at all?

Comment: so they're system calls to the Kernel using the C Standard Lib?

Comment: As stated here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations you don't get a shell unless you explicitly ask for one with `shell=True`, and in that case, on Linux, you get `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: @SamMalayek Yes. If you don't use `shell=True`, it does its own `fork()` and `exec()`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah! Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `shell` is not passed as a keyword argument it uses `fork_exec`, or `_winapi.CreateProceess`

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f3751efb5c8b53b37efbbf75d9422c1d11c01646/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c#L600
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f3751efb5c8b53b37efbbf75d9422c1d11c01646/Modules/_winapi.c#L1062
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e02ab59fdffa0bb841182c30ef1355c89578d945/Lib/subprocess.py#L1770
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e02ab59fdffa0bb841182c30ef1355c89578d945/Lib/subprocess.py#L1434

If `shell=True`:

- **posix** it uses `/bin/sh`, .
- **windows** it uses `cmd.exe`.

See:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1698-L1704
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e02ab59fdffa0bb841182c30ef1355c89578d945/Lib/subprocess.py#L1421-L1425
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e02ab59fdffa0bb841182c30ef1355c89578d945/Lib/subprocess.py#L1670

Comment: Since he doesn't use `shell=True`, this answer isn't really relevant.

Comment: Right, thanks, I'm mainly curious about the software components between Python and the program that's executed if it's not a shell. I'm starting to realize that it must be C system calls.

Comment: @SamMalayek np.

Comment: @SamMalayek, ...I wouldn't really call them "C" system calls -- any C standard-library wrapper like `execlp` eventually goes to an actual syscall, like `execve`, you can invoke without the C library involved at all; hence programs written in languages like Go that don't use libc being able to start other programs.